# Как сделать форматированный ввод в Java? Типа оператора `>>` в плюсах

Tags: java

Как сделать форматированный ввод в Java? Типа оператора `>>` в плюсах.

Comment: [`String format(String format, Object... args)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))?

Comment: @post_zeew а как это к классу привязать?

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Добавьте конкретики.

Comment: @post_zeew для вывода я могу переопределить `toString` в нужном мне классе и далее выводить его с помощью System.out.print, как сделать нечто подобное для ввода?

Comment: Все равно непонятно. Поясните на примере, что конкретно Вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @post_zeew хочу System.in.readmyclass(myclass), а в консоли набрать некий текст который будет нужным образом обрабатываться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно реализовать метод `read()` таким образом:

```
public class MyObject {
    private int mX;
    private int mY;

    public int getX() {
        return mX;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return mY;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + mX + ", " + mY + "]";
    }

    public void read() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите значение x: ");
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            mX = scanner.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Введены некорректные данные!");
            return;
        }

        System.out.print("Введите значение y: ");
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            mY = scanner.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Введены некорректные данные!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Далее:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.read();
```

Также можно сделать чтобы `read()` возвращал `boolean` в зависимости от успешного/неуспешного ввода.